# throw new Error() logs error message twice when using \n in message

Tags: javascript, console, throw, replit

**I have a problem where the console will log an error twice when using \n in the error message.**
**Here is an example:**

```
throw new Error("Vector lengths must be equal");
```

**The code above results in :**
Error: Vector lengths must be equal
As you can see this error message has printed once as expected.

```
throw new Error("Vector lengths must be equal" + "\nVector[0] = 1");
```

**The code above results in :**
Error: Vector lengths must be equal
Vector[0] = 1
Error: Vector lengths must be equal
Vector[0] = 1
Here, I have added \n in the error message to create a break in the error message for increased readability, but as you can see it prints the error message twice which is unexpected and repetitive.
**Please advise me in any way on how I can work around or even fix this problem.**

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in FF nor in Chromium browsers. On which environment are you testing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.
Highly doubt it will work but try it without `+`
Example:
`throw new Error("Vector lengths must be equal\nVector[0] = 1");`

Comment: @Teemu I am using an online IDE called replit and I have now tried testing my code locally and the error mentioned is not produced. So, I believe there may just be something wrong with the IDE that creates this error.

Comment: Maybe you should report a bug. If Michael's suggestion won't fix the issue, there's probably not much we can do here at SO.